# Exception in jQuery(selector [, context])

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Can anybody tell me why I get an exception using the code below?

```
var invalidhtml = '<tr><div id="residualErrors" style="display:none;"></div><form action="" method="post"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></form></tr>';  

var form = $("form", invalidhtml);
```

Comment: This makes no sense, your var `invalidhtml` is not reused and it's content string doesn't have a closing ', furthermore the html in the string is invalid.

Comment: I assume somehtml is supposed to be invalidhtml. In that case, @Clive is correct in that you're passing the wrong data type as the context.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, you are too fast for me :) Have corrected the html (somehtml should have been invalidhtml)) but I'm going to answer this myself as soon as stack overflow lets me, I'm putting it on to save somebody else the strife I went through. Essentially the situation is as follows:

Comment: "The problem is that the html is invalid as there is no td element under the tr element. jQuery can normally handle this but if there is also a table included within the tr element somewhere then it raises an exception."

Comment: Dennis: You can pass a string in as a "Document". see "$("div", xml.responseXML);" on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the html is invalid as there is no "td" element under the "tr" element. jQuery can normally handle this but if there is also a "table" included within the "tr" element somewhere then it raises an exception.

The original place where I had the problem was much more complicated html so I hope it helps somebody.

Any of the validhtml examples below work, the invalid one does not.

```
var invalidhtml = '<tr><form action="" method="post"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table>    </form></tr>';        

var validhtml = '<tr><form action="" method="post"></form></tr>';        

var validhtml2 = '<div><form action="" method="post"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table>    </form></div>';        

var validhtml3 = '<table><tr><td><form action="" method="post"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></form></td></tr></table>';        

var validhtml4 = '<tr><td><form action="" method="post"><table><tr><td></td></tr></table>     </form></td></tr>';        

var form = $("form", validhtml);
form = $("form", validhtml2);
form = $("form", validhtml3);
form = $("form", validhtml4);
form = $("form", invalidhtml); // crash here in ie, proper browsers fail silently
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess by your naming of `somehtml` that you're passing in a string when jQuery is expecting an object.

Comment: You can pass a string in as a "Document". see "$("div", xml.responseXML);" on api.jquery.com/jQuery as an example.